Add node to (predefined) group
I am trying to add a number of nodes to a predefined group. To test this, I have created the following rule to add a membership/relationship when a nodes is updated to the only group I currently have. The rule fires, but no relation is added nor an error displayed. Any suggestions what I have done wrong?
uuid: 62025b6c-7cdb-4222-aa48-63470aac16ce
langcode: nl
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: add_nodes_to_group
label: 'Add nodes to group'
events:
  -
    event_name: 'rules_entity_update:node--article'
description: ''
tags: {  }
config_version: '3'
expression:
  id: rules_rule
  uuid: d5c0e317-1ec2-4413-a905-079e77b5de73
  weight: 0
  conditions:
    id: rules_and
    uuid: 444831be-8d87-4ac9-a517-749b5c64def3
    weight: 0
    conditions:
      -
        id: rules_condition
        uuid: d9110f94-9d29-4b1a-a39e-f02e64b1f431
        weight: 0
        condition_id: rules_entity_is_of_bundle
        negate: false
        context_values:
          type: node
          bundle: article
        context_mapping:
          entity: node
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          bundle:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
  actions:
    id: rules_action_set
    uuid: a8ad7ead-57e4-485e-9dab-0b6496b52ef4
    weight: 0
    actions:
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 8628d643-939f-4dbc-9411-9c002323d75d
        weight: -50
        action_id: rules_entity_fetch_by_id
        context_values:
          type: node
        context_mapping:
          entity_id: node.nid.value
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping:
          entity_fetched: entity_fetched_node
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 9fcf11df-c6b2-4b1a-8071-467a37f1e4e0
        weight: -49
        action_id: rules_system_message
        context_values:
          type: status
          repeat: false
        context_mapping:
          message: entity_fetched_node.title.value
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          repeat:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: e0fca77c-ba6e-4405-a0d9-9e3563433df2
        weight: -48
        action_id: rules_entity_fetch_by_id
        context_values:
          type: group
          entity_id: '1'
        context_mapping: {  }
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          entity_id:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping:
          entity_fetched: entity_fetched_group
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 0d4876e5-4fc8-4220-906a-0c34760f5499
        weight: -47
        action_id: rules_system_message
        context_values:
          type: status
          repeat: false
        context_mapping:
          message: entity_fetched_group.label.value
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          repeat:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 4043147b-3b26-4cac-a950-260b1df21791
        weight: -46
        action_id: 'rules_entity_create:group_relationship'
        context_values:
          type: private_group-group_node-article
        context_mapping:
          gid: entity_fetched_group.id.value
          entity_id: entity_fetched_node.nid.value
          plugin_id: node.title.value
          group_type: entity_fetched_group.type.target_id
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 11d77df8-4476-48a9-92b0-0d8e22cd0d87
        weight: 0
        action_id: rules_entity_save
        context_values:
          immediate: '1'
        context_mapping:
          entity: group_relationship_created
        context_processors:
          immediate:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }


Add a "Save entity" action to save your new entity.

Thanks, how could I have missed that!
I have added the save entity group_relationship_created. It is now adding the entity, but it does so indefinitely, in stead of one time. I cannot figure out why it is doing that.

The Rule will be fired every time you update any article. I can't answer what is best for your needs, but you can look at things like triggering the Rule only when the article is created for the first time, or adding an addition condition(s) to see if the article is already part of a group before you add it to the group again.

The trigger is a node which has been updated. So my intention was to add the group only to nodes of type article and that the group was added once. Steps: edit the article, then save. In stead of once, it is added multiple times until stackoverflow. I cannot discover why it is looping.
